# * and ** difference

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

What is difference between `*` and `**`? Why `.**` is not compiling while using `pattern.compile(".**");`?

Comment: For `.**`, what do you think the second `*` is supposed to be applied to?

Comment: What do you want it to match?

Comment: @lbarros just a string. Not file path.

Comment: @azurefrog hm.. I am little confused with `*` and `**` for string matching. Thats why I ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Java [*Quantifiers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) reference:

```
Greedy  Reluctant   Possessive  Meaning
X?      X??         X?+         X, once or not at all
X*      X*?         X*+         X, zero or more times
X+      X+?         X++         X, one or more times
X{n}    X{n}?       X{n}+       X, exactly n times
X{n,}   X{n,}?      X{n,}+      X, at least n times
X{n,m}  X{n,m}?     X{n,m}+     X, at least n but not more than m times
```

**There is no `**` quantifier**. When you use `+` after `+`, `*` or `?` (or even `{n,m}`), you can create a *possessive* quantifier (see the table above), but adding a `*` quantifier after a `*` is considered a **user error**.

That is why `.*` would match 0+ characters other than a newline (without the `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier) and `.**` throws an exception.

Note that online regex testers also warn you of this problem: [*Dangling meta character '*' near index 2 .** ^*](http://fiddle.re/6xkxea) (same warning appears at [OCPSoft regex tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/)).

Comment: Okay, got it. But I still can't understand the following: when user searching, for example, by article id, and he wants to retrieve all articles, he can request by `*` or by `**`. What is the difference between this two?

Comment: What do you mean? If you need to match any string with a regex, even an empty one, you need to use `(?s)^.*$`. If you allow using `*` to retrieve something, it is no longer a regex, it is a *wildcard*.

Comment: Oh, wildcard, really. Thanks. And what is the difference between `*` and `**`?

Comment: If it is a wildcard? Then `**` means *fetch me all there is and then all the rest*. Not much sense, isn't there? The second `*` does not match anything. But that is *pattern matching* that is not regex-based.

Comment: Got it. So, there is no much difference between `*` and `**` when searching by any string?

Comment: Again, if `*` is a wildcard, it matches 0+ any characters in any string. When you ask for everything-everything, you will still get just everything, not the double of everything, right? :)

Comment: Yup :) Now I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When evaluating regular expressions, `*` is a metacharacter that means that the preceding character occurs 0 or more times.

When you write `.**`, that breaks down into `.*` (which means 0 or more of any character) followed by `*`, where there is no preceding character, so the pattern can't compile.

Answer (score 2):

`.` means "(almost) any character".

`*` means "match the previous character 0 or more times"

The second `*` means nothing in this context.

Comment: I'm curious, what does `.` not match? I was under the impression that it matched any character.

Comment: @BethanyLouise, it doesn't match line breaks by default.

Comment: *The second \* means nothing in this context* is not true. It is still a quantifier, but a misplaced one that throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`*` inside a regex, is a **[quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)**, if you want to use it without any special meaning, escape it `\*`.

`.*` - **will match any single character** that is **NOT** a line break character (line feed, carriage return, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) `.*`
**Between zero and unlimited times**, as **many times as possible**, giving back as needed (**greedy**) `*` Your regular expression **may find zero-length matches**.
Java 8 allows a zero-length match at the position where the previous match ends.